# Kill working on terminal but not in cronJob

Tags: node.js, shell

I have a problem with the command kill in the shell.
I am using `kill -9 $(lsof -i:42042 -t)` to kill the process working on port 42042 , it is working in the terminal but when i execute my cron job the log is:
`kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]`
here is the content of my crontab:

```
 * * * * *   kill -9 $(lsof -i:42042 -t) >>/cron1.log 2>&1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Specify the full pathname of `lsof`. E.g. `/usr/bin/lsof` (or wherever your lsof command is located) instead of just `lsof`.

Comment: Thanks ! it's solved